# Should I register both front-end and api apps in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have a single page application hosted as a static on Azure storage account. The SPA is registered in AD B2C, and it is possible to log in alright using msal. Now I want to call my REST API, also hosted on Azure, but only allow authorization if logged in. Should I register the API as a separate app in B2C, or should I use the same registration when setting up the WebApiAuthentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should register the Web API as a separate app registration and expose scopes via the "Expose an API" tab in B2C. Once you create the scopes, you can grant access to your client app registration using the "API Permissions" tab. You will be required to grant admin consent at that time.

Refer to [How to access two separate Web APIs protected using Azure AD B2C from a web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65003748/how-to-access-two-separate-web-apis-protected-using-azure-ad-b2c-from-a-web-app) if you are creating multiple services that are called by the same client.