# How to access two separate Web APIs protected using Azure AD B2C from a web app

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have two separeate dotnet core apis(API1 & API2) that are protected using azure ad b2c. Both these apis are registered on the b2c tenant and have their scopes exposed.
We have a client web applicaiton that is to access the above protected apis. This web app has been registered as a applicaiton in b2c tenant and has api permissions set for the above apis with proper scopes defined.

We use MSAL.net with a signinpolicy to sign the user in to the web app.
the authentication call requires scopes to mentioned. So we add API1's scope in the call.
(note : one scope of a single resource can be added in a auth call shown below)

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Required for Azure webapps, as by default they force TLS 1.2 and this project attempts 1.0
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // ASP.NET web host compatible cookie manager
            CookieManager = new SystemWebChunkingCookieManager()
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // Generate the metadata address using the tenant and policy information
                MetadataAddress = String.Format(Globals.WellKnownMetadata, Globals.Tenant, Globals.DefaultPolicy),

                // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
                ClientId = Globals.ClientId,
                RedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,

                // Specify the callbacks for each type of notifications
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                },

                // Specify the claim type that specifies the Name property.
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    ValidateIssuer = false
                },

                // Specify the scope by appending all of the scopes requested into one string (separated by a blank space)
                Scope = $"openid profile offline_access {Globals.ReadTasksScope} {Globals.WriteTasksScope}",

                // ASP.NET web host compatible cookie manager
                CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
            }
        );
    }
```

The OnAuthorizationCodeRecieved method in Startup.Auth.cs recieved the code recieved as a result of above auth call and uses it to get a access token based on the scopes provided and stores it in the cache. shown below

```
private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification)
    {
        try
        {
            /*
             The `MSALPerUserMemoryTokenCache` is created and hooked in the `UserTokenCache` used by `IConfidentialClientApplication`.
             At this point, if you inspect `ClaimsPrinciple.Current` you will notice that the Identity is still unauthenticated and it has no claims,
             but `MSALPerUserMemoryTokenCache` needs the claims to work properly. Because of this sync problem, we are using the constructor that
             receives `ClaimsPrincipal` as argument and we are getting the claims from the object `AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context`.
             This object contains the property `AuthenticationTicket.Identity`, which is a `ClaimsIdentity`, created from the token received from
             Azure AD and has a full set of claims.
             */
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClient = MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication(new ClaimsPrincipal(notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity));

            // Upon successful sign in, get & cache a token using MSAL
            AuthenticationResult result = await confidentialClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(Globals.Scopes, notification.Code).ExecuteAsync();
            

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                ReasonPhrase = $"Unable to get authorization code {ex.Message}.".Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "")
            });
        }
    }
```

This access token is then used in the TasksController to call AcquireTokenSilent which retrieves the access token from the cache, which is then used in the api call.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the token with the specified scopes
            var scope = new string[] { Globals.ReadTasksScope };
            
            IConfidentialClientApplication cca = MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication();
            var accounts = await cca.GetAccountsAsync();
            AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilent(scope, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();
            
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, apiEndpoint);

            // Add token to the Authorization header and make the request
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            // Handle the response
            switch (response.StatusCode)
            {
                case HttpStatusCode.OK:
                    String responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    JArray tasks = JArray.Parse(responseString);
                    ViewBag.Tasks = tasks;
                    return View();
                case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
                    return ErrorAction("Please sign in again. " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                default:
                    return ErrorAction("Error. Status code = " + response.StatusCode + ": " + response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
        {
            /*
                If the tokens have expired or become invalid for any reason, ask the user to sign in again.
                Another cause of this exception is when you restart the app using InMemory cache.
                It will get wiped out while the user will be authenticated still because of their cookies, requiring the TokenCache to be initialized again
                through the sign in flow.
            */
            return new RedirectResult("/Account/SignUpSignIn?redirectUrl=/Tasks");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ErrorAction("Error reading to do list: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The issue is the code recieved by the OnAuthorizationCodeRecieved method can only be used to get the access token for API1 since its scope was mentioned in auth call. When trying to get access token for API2 it returns null.

Question : How to configure the web app so that it is able to access multiple protected apis?

Please suggest.

The code can be found from the sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single access token can only contain scopes for a single audience.

You have 2 options:

1. Combine both services into a single app registration and expose different scopes.
2. Request multiple tokens - one per service. If your SSO policy is configured correctly in B2C, this should happen silently unbeknownst to the user.

I recommend using option 1 if you own both services (which it sounds like you do). A few tips related to this option.

- When declaring the scopes in the combined app registration, use the dot-syntax {LogicalService}.{Operation}. If you do this, the scopes will be grouped by logical service within the Azure portal.
- Make sure you are validating scopes in your service. Validating only the audience is not good enough and would allow an attacker to make lateral movements with a token bound for another service.

Comment: How do I validate the scope of access token?

Comment: This article from Auth0 has a really nice tutorial of how to create a custom Authorize attribute that grabs the scope claim ("scp") off the token and validates the scope for each controller method. This can certainly be done more globally if you only have 1 scope per service. https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/aspnet-core-webapi/01-authorization

Comment: Would you please also tell me that How to deal with multiple APIs with Azure B2C. I have production and testing platform ( means two API links ) so how can i achieve this goal that from front end app it will go to both according to our need?

Comment: I recommend using multiple B2C tenants - one for each environment. This initially seems daunting to keep the app registrations, custom policies, and web files in sync, but you can automate the deployment of both through the Graph API and just swap out the environment-specific variables. Higher upfront investment, but will pay off in the long run.